# How do I log out of an account in Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51, logout

How do I log out of the Area 51 site? I clicked log-in and it automatically logged me in using the account that I was using on Meta Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Area 51 has a different design from other Stack Exchange sites. Click on Stack Exchange Hamburger menu which is to the top right corner. You will see a drop down menu. Click 'log out'. If you are a registered user, you will be shown your Open ID. Click log out on the redirected page again. You will be logged out successfully.

[image: Stack Exchange hamburger dropdown on Area 51]