# How can I completely log out of Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51, logout

I've accidentally logged in with the wrong account and I wanted to log out. I've succeed to log out from Stack Exchange, but when I came to Area 51 I see that I'm still logged in.

Is there a way to log out from Area 51?

---

The proposed duplicate *[How do I log out of an account in Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319676/how-do-i-log-out-of-an-account-in-area-51)* does not answer my question, because I do not see any [hamburger menu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_button) either in the top left corner and in the top right corner.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I log out of an account in Area 51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319676/how-do-i-log-out-of-an-account-in-area-51) - found using a [site search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Area+51+log+out).

Comment: It's a known bug that [the top bar on Area 51 is malformed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377733/the-top-bar-on-area-51-is-malformed) so it doesn't look like in the screenshot as that was taken before the bug occurred. You can get the same dropdown menu by clicking the text "Stack Exchange".

Comment: Or you can visit this [logout link](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/logout).